# Using noise threshold of 0.1 produces a better result than 0.01

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I was doing final render of my project. I hit F12 and I start rendering. After a while the result is horrible and grainy. This was strange since my viewport seemed to render just fine. Then I tried setting the noise threshold of the final render to 0.1 instead of 0.01 and got much better result. Why is it that "better" noise threshold produces worse results?
Below are my findings.
[image: Render result with noise threshold of 0.1]

[image: Render result with noise threshold of 0.01]

Comment: Which one is which? Which one do you consider "better"? JPEG compression is really poor choice for evaluating noise. Is there any denoising being applied? That would throw off any judgement we could potentially make.

Comment: @Duarte Farrajota Ramos The lower one is the one with 0.01. And yes I know that jpeg is poor choiec for evaluating noise. What I actually mean are those black spots that you can see for example at the brick in the background of the photo. Using noise as my choice of words was bad since I should have used the correct word from the beginning(english isnt my first language) There is denoising in both images. but the result looks almost the same without it

Comment: You should edit your question and clarify that, otherwise I suspect people will have a hard time helping. We don't know what the scene is supposed to look like so we can't tell apart what is unwanted noise, what are denoise artifacts and what are actual scene details from those images.